# How I can export pdf file in .cdr. (File made in adobe photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, pdf, print-production, corel-draw

As printer guy said he needs .cdr file for printing. I have coral but, don't know how to use coral draw. Please help me. This is very big problem to me right now. Anyone know easiest way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **zero** conversion between Photoshop and CorelDraw. Essentially you would need to remake the file entirely using CorelDraw. There's nothing you can do to simply "convert" a file from Photoshop (.psd) to CorelDraw (.cdr).

If you merely *place* the Photoshop file into a CorelDraw document and then save/export as a PDF... it's *pointless*. You may as well deliver the Photoshop file. Using CorelDraw in this manner to generate a PDF does *nothing* but add a superfluous file wrapper before the PDF save/export, it doesn't "convert" anything.

If you have a file in Photoshop, you can merely *save that file* as a PDF. But there may be some reason a "printer guy" is specifically asking for a CorelDraw file... CorelDraw in itself is fairly uncommon in commercial printing circles, although not unheard of. And he, of course, may have suggested CorelDraw because you told him you have that application.

Beyond this, it is difficult to give any direction without understanding *why* a Photoshop file insufficient, *why* a PDF from Photoshop is insufficient, and *why* a CorelDraw file is *actually* necessary.

Essentially, without actually seeing the file in question and knowing how you are wanting it reproduced, there's no telling why the guy wants a CorelDraw file. Worse case scenario would be to save the Photoshop file as a .tiff ... which is more than suitable for commercial printing, provided the file's resolution is high enough (240ppi minimum).

<sub>Also, it's not uncommon for a printing provider to ask you for a different file format because they simply *don't want* to work on your project. Rather than merely telling you "no", they request a format they are aware you probably don't understand or have or can't create easily. That way you walk away feeling as if *your file* was incorrect rather than feeling like they refused your project. I **can't** say this is the the case for you. But it does happen.</sub>

Comment: "Worse case scenario" is that the print guy needs a vector file, or the user designed an entire magazine in Ps, in RGB in low resolution... I can imagine worse cases...

Comment: Yeah possibly @Rafael I'm sure you can imagine all the headaches I can. But even if it's something like a "magazine" each page *could* be saved as a PDF... But.. I'm guessing it was more a "polite" way of refusing the work. I've never heard *anyone* requesting a CorelDraw file unless it was for vinyl cutting. But that's in my world, not everyones.

Comment: ..hmm.. I don't see how this answer is "incorrect" or "unhelpful" and deserving of a downvote... oh well...

Comment: Actually Here in India, Maximum peoples here in India use coral for printing. Whatever It you want print and when they try to print a other format except .cdr then they demand cdr file to adjust sizes or logos etc this is the problem.

Comment: +1 from me to counteract the downvote which is completely unwarranted.

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr --- It's not the rep that makes me wonder. I haven't cared about rep in quite some time.. It's the sentiment.. i.e. what does someone think is "unhelpful" here - or was it just a "personality" vote.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. This is a long comment.

I do not want to be rude. You do not have a Corel Draw problem. You have a communication problem.

---

**I. What is the project about?**

Do you need a vector file? Is it for something like laser cutting or a vinyl sign?

Is it digital paint? Is it a logo? Is it a brochure?

Do you know the difference between a raster image or a vector image? Is it an image at all or the design of a magazine?

If it is a raster image, (which I doubt, because they would either simply flatten it or ask a simple format like tiff or even JPG) is it at a correct resolution?

**II. Ask "the print guy"**

He has already seen the project, he knows why he is asking that you should do it in a different program. If the project is not suitable to be done in Photoshop, there are specific reasons for it. You do not design a brochure on Ps, or a flyer, or a magazine.

If you do not know how to use a program, you can pay for someone to help you.

But asking on a forum (very good forum I should say) without information is the same problem you have with your print provider. Information. Clarify this with him and make specific steps to solve your problem.

Comment: Thankyou So much for your information. I will try to talk with printer guy regarding this thing. By the way I have a PDF file of a Thankyou Card, It has a solid bg color and text on it. I convert psd into pdf.